# How to create a new vertex group and link meshes to bones (armature) in Blender?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups, empty

How to create a new vertex group and link meshes to bones (armature) in Blender?

I deleted initial/original armature and vertex group I had to start over, but that is giving me some issues to assign the vertex group to the mesh (in fact vertex group is gone even when new armature is added).

I repositioned bones, selected armature (yellow outline) and body parts (orange), set parent to armature deform: with empty groups.

[image: armature selected first then body and head selected]

Edit mode: object data properties > Vertex Groups

While working on this, the overall sturcuture (the armature) was not moving and was not connected to the body. The mesh would not follow along the bones.

**I deleted the entire vertex group (-)**, cleared the parent, to start over. And this caused the problem.

Whenever I add a new armature, renamed every bone, but I noticed that the vertex group was empty.

[image: Re-added the vertex group]

Is there a way to fix this?
How can I get update (automatically) this new vertex group (new added structure)

I did rename everything, but whenever I try to assign the selected mesh to vertex (I am not even sure if I am selecting the right vertex group).

- List item

Some tutorials I have been checking out regarding rigging:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3yHAawEVes

https://youtube.com/shorts/DZXN511-l3E?si=tCVrQmBUgfXDkcIP

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E3Qk10EoFA